# “Live URL Testing" shows a cached version of my Bubble.io website when testing the URLs using the GoogleBot crawler, through Google Search Console

Tags: browser-cache, google-search-console, googlebot, google-crawlers, bubble.io

When crawling a completely new URL, the googlebot crawler will always fetch the latest version of the page the first time it is tested,

**After this first instance of a new URL being tested, it continues to load the same cached copy even when the “Live URL Testing” option is used**.

By going through the HTML I’ve confirmed that all the changes in site elements since the initial crawl of these pages, have **not** been reflected on GSC.

The regular users however, are receiving the updated version of the page immediately.

For example, when crawling this URL through GSC:

https://app.aventure.vc/research/companies/bettercloud-new-york-ny-usa

The screenshot provided by GSC:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V9zb.png

**

The content in the first image has been the same for over 3 days, since changes were made to the website and that page in particular.**

The actual content on the site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Tgu.png

**(Note that the values within the info cards in both images are different)**

**How do I disable this caching and have the crawler always receive the latest version of the site?**

These are the relevant meta tags I have placed in the header of the website, in an attempt to stop the crawler from receiving cached content but the crawler still continues to receive the same cached pages.

**<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />**

**<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />**

**<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />**

**<meta name="robots" content="all">**